# Wörter ohne Konsonanten

Tags: single-word-request

Was sind in der deutschen Standardsprache Beispiele für Wörter, die keine Konsonanten haben?

Bisher fiel mir Folgendes ein:

> **Au(e), Ei**

Gibt es mehr solche Wörter?

Comment: Mit `egrep "^[AEIOUaeiouYyÖÄÜöüä]+/" ~/lib/dicts/de_DE.dic` finde ich nicht mehr in meinen Offlinewörterbüchern, allerdings findet das nicht mal das Faultier Ai. Dennoch stimmt mich das pessimistisch für eine großes Community-Wiki-Projekt. Fremdländische Ortsnamen u.ä. mögen noch die Listen erweitern. Allerdings habe ich eine Freundin mit 4 unterschiedlichen Vokalen im Vornamen aufzubieten, und zwar ohne a.

Comment: Ich habe die Frage um "in der deutschen Standardsprache" ergänzt, denn sobald man Dialekte zulässt, wird's bunt. - Gegen Wörtersammelanfragen habe ich persönlich nichts einzuwenden, aber in der Tat sollte man dann die Antwort als Gemeinschaftswiki anlegen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diese sind uns spontan eingefallen:

> - das [Aa](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Aa_Kot) (feste menschliche Ausscheidung)
> - das [Ai](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ai) (Faultier)
> - [ui](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ui) (Ausruf staunender Bewunderung)
> - [aua](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aua), das Aua (Schmerzlaut, Verletzung/Wunde)
> - [ey](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ey) (»Mann, ey«).
> - [aye](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/aye) (wird gebraucht in Legislativorganen bei mündlicher Abstimmung, in der Seemannssprache, in Schottland, dem nördlichen England, dem nördlichen Irland, sonst veraltet)
> - [ia](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ia) (Interjektion, Tierlaut, besonderer Tierlaut des Esels)
> - [a](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/a#a_(Deutsch))  (eins a!)
> - [o](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/o) (du fröhliche)

Comment: +1 für das Faultier. Wer "ui" sagt, sagt aber auch bald "eueueu!".

Comment: @userunkown Eieiei!

Comment: Wäre es wohl zu verquer, noch die *EU* hier anzufügen? Natürlich unter Vorbringung des Arguments, dass diese inzwischen ihren Abkürzungscharakter verloren hat und zum normalen Wort geworden ist...

Comment: Vokal**laute** oder Vokal**buchstaben**? Je nachdem zählt "Y" zu den Konsonanten...

Comment: Mundartlich: "i" (=ich); "a" (=auch). Wie ist es mit "eh"? Könnte man es zählen, denn H ist wohl kein echter Konsonant?

Comment: @IQV - Wenn man Vokalphoneme zulässt (statt sich auf Grapheme zu beschränken), werden auch das **Ohr** und **Uhr** zu reinen Vokalwörtern: **Oa**, **Ua**.